# Setting in Visual Studio where indent style is set?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 questions

**Q1:**

I have read about various coding [indent styles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) like Allman, K&R etc.

What i want to know is where is the setting in VS(2010) where all these can be set?

**Q2:**

When I press `Ctrl + K` and `Ctrl + D` after each other. It corrects formatting like where there are 2 spaces b/w words it reduces them to one.

Similarly is there any shortcuts that removes extra emptylines between 2 lines of codes?

My situation is that I was given a code where extra enter were pressed between 2 lines of code. How can i remove it?

Comment: Tools --> Options ... --> Text Editor --> C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. Under Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->Indentation [image: Indent Style]
change the settings as per your need.
 Also check **Formatting->New Lines.**

Q2. There are many ways to remove blank lines
1st Solution:
1. Click Ctrl+H (quick replace)
2. Tick "Use Regular Expressions"
3. In Find specify "^$\n"
4. In Replace box delete everything.
5. Click "Replace All"
All Blank lines will be deleted. :)
^ Means Beginning of line 
$ Means End of line
2nd Solution:
Check the VS addins like [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper) or [CodeMaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496/?SRC=VSIDE) which does the code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Q1: You'll find a bunch of formatting settings under Tools-->Options-->Text Editor