# Indentation style in visual studio

Tags: c#, coding-style

When I type this In visual studio

```
if(){
}
```

It automatically changes it to:

```
if()
{
}
```

How can I make VS keep the first indentation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631091/setting-in-visual-studio-where-indent-style-is-set

Comment: You may want to check the Microsoft Guidelines. Although they are not binding, the C# community is pretty much set on using them and going against it will make your code stand out. Which is not actually a good thing, guidelines exist for a reason.

Comment: That first style is a throwback to the days of 25 line text terminals (when programmers were real programmers....).

Answer (score 6):

Tools> Options> Text Editor> C#> Formatting> New Lines